# Ignore specific error conditions with SFTP/SCP File transfer

Tags: bash, sftp, scp

I am trying to bash script a daily file transfer between 2 machines. The script runs on the destination machine and pulls a file from the source machine.  Occasionally the source machine will not have a file ready, this is acceptable.

I would like the script to exit 0 on successful transfer, and when there is no file available to be transferred. I would like the script to exit non 0 on any other failure condition (connectivity, etc).

I tried the following 2 approaches, I found with SCP the return code is always 1 no matter what the actual error, so its hard for the script to differentiate between my acceptable error condition, and others.

The sftp method seems to always return 0 no matter what takes place during the command. Any suggestions?

```
scpGet(){
  echo "Attempting File Transfer"
  scp -P $REMOTEPORT $REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEPATH $LOCALPATH
  echo $?
}
sftpGet(){
cd $LOCALPATH
sftp -P $REMOTEPORT $REMOTEHOST << EOF
get $REMOTEPATH
quit
EOF
echo $?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't validated this, so please check that it actually does what you want -
but you are apparently running scp with no password, so you can probably execute arbitrary code remotely to test for the existence of the file. Just be careful.

```
scpGet() {
  echo "Attempting File Transfer"
  if scp -P $REMOTEPORT $REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEPATH $LOCALPATH
  then echo "$( ls -l $LOCALPATH) - successfully retrieved"
  elif ssh -P $REMOTEPORT ls -l $REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEPATH
  then echo "$REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEPATH exists, but I can't retrieve it!" >&2
       exit $oopsieCode 
  elif (( 2 == $rc )) # ls failed to find the file - verify this code
  then echo "File not ready. Ignoring."
  else : handle errors other than "not found"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Paul, you led me down the right path, furthermore now, I am just checking if the file is there first, and aborting the rest of the script if its not.

Comment: Glad to help. :)